# Advice on ultrasonic transmission protocol

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing, transmission

I am working on an application that will receive ultrasonic waves and it will perform different actions based on the input. At some point, I am going to need that this ultrasonic waves to be **unique** for my application in the sense that I don't want other waves to interfere. 
Can you please give me some guidance on the protocols for making a wave sound "unique"? There are commercials applications for that like [cue audio](http://cueaudio.com). I am planning to write the application using Android. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incidentally there is a related [stack exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what frequency range are you thinking of ?  normal mic or special input source ?

Comment: @ScottStensland around 20 KHz which is apparently close to the limit of a standard microphone.

Answer (score 2):

"Direct sequence spread spectrum" (DSSS) transmission is used to make communication resistant to jamming and interference, which seems to cover your use case as well.

It's reasonably easy to implement digitally.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum

Answer (score 1):

This might be more of a dsp question, but you could use frequency shift keying, where you encode a pattern as a series of frequencies and then recover them: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/digital_communication/digital_communication_frequency_shift_keying.htm

If its for rangefinding, have a look at chirp signals used in radar: http://www.dspguide.com/ch11/6.htm Not exactly what you asked I know but probably of interest as well. These are commonly used in radar systems.